# Creating an aws target group with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, ansible

What Im trying to accomplish is to create a network load balancer target group from dynamically generated list of instances.

brokerInstancesList is a list of instance ids. I need to iterate over this list and add them as targets to this target group.

```
- name: "Create 9092 target group"
  elb_target_group:
    name: "tg-{{ ClusterName }}"
    protocol: tcp
    port: 9092
    vpc_id: "{{ VPCID }}"
    targets:
      - Id: "{{ item }}"
        Port: 9092
    state: present
  loop: "{{ brokerInstancesList }}"
```

The issue with my attempt above is that only the last entry in the brokerInstancesList is kept. Something like the below is what I need.

```
- name: "Create 9092 target group"
  elb_target_group:
    name: "tg-{{ ClusterName }}"
    protocol: tcp
    port: 9092
    vpc_id: "{{ VPCID }}"
    targets:
      {% for item in {{ brokerInstancesList }} -%}
      - Id: "{{ apple }}"
        Port: 9092
      {%- endfor %}
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the list of targets in a previous step:

```
  - name: Create the custom fact for targets                                       
    set_fact:                                                                      
      target_data: "{{ target_data|default([]) + [{'Id': item, 'Port': 9092 }]}}"
    with_items: "{{ brokerInstancesList }}"
```

And then use the `target_data` list for the `targets` attribute in the `elb_target_group` task.

Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32218#issuecomment-339792059

Answer (score 1):

Use elb_target module to implement it:

- name: Gather facts for all new proxy instances
  ec2_instance_facts:
  filters:
    "tag:Name": "{{ ec2_tag_proxy }}"
  register: ec2_proxy
- elb_target_group:
  name: uat-target-proxy
  protocol: http
  port: 80
  vpc_id: vpc-4e6e8112
  deregistration_delay_timeout: 60
  stickiness_enabled: True
  stickiness_lb_cookie_duration: 86400
  health_check_path: /
  successful_response_codes: "200"
  health_check_interval: "20"
  state: present
- elb_target:
  target_group_name: uat-target-proxy
  target_id: "{{ item.instance_id }}"
  target_port: 80
  state: present
  with_items: "{{ ec2_proxy.instances }}"
  when: ec2_proxy.instances|length > 0